# How to configure editor component to enable source code formatting?

Tags: primeng, quill

Im trying to use the primeng editor (which uses quill) for an in-browser editor where users can paste source code snippets. How do I configure the primeng editor (or quill) to format common code formats just as typescript, javascript, c# etc?

I create an editor defined like this:

```
 <p-editor formControlName="editor" [style]="{'height':'320px'}" name="text"></p-editor>
```

Which then renders like this:

Source code with no formatting.
------------------------
[image]
Looking at the Quill website, if I paste in some sample code here
https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/

I then see the content rendered like this:

------------------------

[image]

Comment: Please see https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/syntax/